# Executing efbundle (post dotnet ef migrations budle) not able to load Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions file/nuget

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, nuget-package, entity-framework-migrations

My solution has different projects (all dotnet 7):

1. Core
2. DataAccess (DbContext source project)
3. Service
4. UI

I am able to run my solution just fine.

I am using code first approach for Db migrations using `dotnet ef` **version 7.0.4**

The connection string comes from UI layer using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.
For migration steps the connection string is directly read from appsettings.json from UI layer as follows:

```
        public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).
                AddJsonFile(@Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + ".<UI project path>.//appsettings.json").Build();

            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyAppConnection");
...
```

Everything works fine when I am doing migrations manually and update database using dotnet ef cli commands.

I started working with [dotnet ef migrations bundles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#bundles) for migrations from relese pipelines.
When I create bundle using `dotnet ef migrations bundle -f -v --self-contained`
the `efbundle.exe` is generated

But when executing the `efbudle.exe`, there is an error as follows:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at DataAccess.Dbcontexts.DesignTimeDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(String[] args)
...
```

I've tried using different options for generating bundle:

```
1)  dotnet ef migrations bundle -f -v
2)  dotnet ef migrations bundle --self-contained --startup-project "<Path To UI Project>\API.csproj" -f -v
3)  dotnet ef migrations bundle --self-contained --context MyContext --project "<Path To DataAccess Project>\dataAccess.csproj" --startup-project "<Path To UI Project>\API.csproj" -f -v
```

And executing the efbundle:

```
.\efbundle.exe --connection 'MyConnectionString'
.\efbundle.exe
```

Everytime its Configuration nuget file not able to load.

Please suggest how to debug/resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a package dependency problem (and not efcore problem) as some dependencies were not loading due to `PrivateAssets` property selectively enabled for the dependency: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`.

Changing the property `PrivateAssets` to `none` in the `DataAccess.csproj` file resolved the problem and now the `efbundle.exe` works as expected.

After the change the PackageReference entry of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` looks like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.4">
    <PrivateAssets>none</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Also, the `appsettings.json` file is also needed with the `efbundle.exe` to work (same folder).

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work for me, so far nothing has worked. Keep getting `No frameworks were found.` despite it definitely being installed.

Comment: @MichaelBrown Are you facing the same error as I did about not being able to execute the generated efbundle.exe?